# Количество вопросов от студентов удваивается во время учебного года

Tags: обсуждение, цифры

В каникулы, количество вопросов из университетов падает с 10% до 5% от общего числа вопросов страны, согласно данным за 3 года на Stack Overflow.

Интересный момент, что вопросы задаются на протяжении всего учебного года, а не только во время сессии (не смотря на известный стереотип — данные его не подтверждают).

[image: % of questions from universities over the year]
из блога [How Do Students Use Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/How-Do-Students-Use-Stack-Oveflow/?cb=1)

Comment: Очень радостно видеть, что стереотип не подтверждается.

Comment: Эм.. А как определялось? По ip университета?

Comment: Это не стереотип, это факт. Просто во время занятий задаются нормальные вопросы, а во время сессии - всякий шлак.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы имеете право на своё мнение, но не на свои факты. Покажите цифры или не нужно делать громких заявлений.

Comment: Меня больше удивляет очень очевидная просадка в конце мая-июне. Весенняя сессия в моих краях обычно в этот период и проходит. И огромное падение в январе - в моих краях зимние сессии как раз в это время. Когда проводятся сессии в университетах указанных стран?

Comment: @Qwertiy , оказывается даже хуже - по названию провайдера, с IP которого был задан вопрос: "asked from an ISP whose name contained "University", "College", or "Institute of"". Т.е. общежития, wifi на территории университета и прочее в этом духе и только большие университеты, которые заморочились своим ISP. Даже вопрос с мобильного интернета уже в выборку не попадёт.

Comment: @Мелкий, а во время сессий все задают из дома, а не из компьютерного класса университета ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy речь в посте о западных университетах. Там очень даже в традиции готовиться в самом университете (чаще всего в библиотеке).