# 250 вопросов в день!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, статистика

Коллеги, поздравляю нас всех! :) На прошлой неделе мы преодолели новый рубеж — 250 вопросов в день!

[image: 250 вопросов в день на Stack Overflow на русском]

Спасибо тем, кто делится своими проблемами с сообществом! Спасибо тем, кто помогает их решать! Спасибо нам всем за доверие и человеческое отношение друг к другу!

Создаваемые нами знания бесценны для русскоязычного сообщества программистов.

Comment: Круто, еще бы справиться с задачей прививания высокой планки качества вопросов, а то ощутимая доля из них - полный шок

Comment: Есть ли статистика по проценту закрываемых/удаляемых вопросов? В идеале за промежуток времени, например за последний месяц.

Comment: 250 это единоразово столько было у нас вопросов в какой-то день? Или это среднее за последний месяц, например?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, среднее за несколько дней, насколько я помню.

Comment: Вопросы - это хорошо. Но, по моим субъективным ощущениям, процент ответов стал меньше чем было раньше. Количество задающих вопросы и количество отвечающих - непропорционально увеличивается.

Comment: @Qwertiy 244 questions/day сейчас отображается

Comment: @АндрейNOP Среднее за две недели.

Comment: @yolosora Да, такую статистику, на сколько я знаю, можно получить.

Comment: @АндрейNOP *244* ... скатились уже :(

Comment: @yolosora: [статистика здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last14days) такая же как на SO на английском (только там вопросов на порядок/два больше, но здесь чуть больше шансов ответ получить): один из десяти закрываются

Comment: @jfs ссылка, очевидно, является для меня мало полезной)

Comment: @yolosora ссылка не для вас, а чтобы я знал откуда я эти цифры взял и другие люди могли проверить

Comment: @yolosora, за 2 недели: "Вопросов закрыто: 381 / Вопросов задано: 3750 / Процент закрытия 10,16%"

Comment: @РашенБеар, конечно наблюдается разрыв в вопросах и ответов на них. Явное влияние оказывают наступающие каникулы ИМХО :) Чем и объясняется уровень и суть вопросов, а также языки программирования, которые лидируют.. яваскрипт в топе!

Comment: @NewView "про каникулы" — эта одна из очевидных простых и неправильных согласно реальным данным идей. [Количество вопросов от студентов удваивается во время учебного года](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4807/23044)

Comment: А сколько всего вопросов было импортировано с хешкода на дату рождения ruSO? А то общее среднее так-то под 280...

Answer (score 9):

Лично мне нравится не количество, а качество! У нас из 250 вопросов 20% (а то и больше) идут вопросы либо как задания (поручения к выполнению), либо очень низкого качества.

Большинство из них не удаляются, к сожалению. А некоторые даже разыгрываются на конкурсной основе. К примеру, вот человек хочет «[Управление картинкой с БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827667/#comment1328803_827694)». И мы это пропустили в конкурсы. Но это только один пример.

Кто-то потратит свои силы и время, перечитывая весь этот мусор (по сути), и ему из-за этого не хватит сил и/или времени доискаться до нужного ответа. А кому-то не хватит сил и/или времени кому-то помочь. Спрашивается, зачем мы всё это оставляем и копим, и для кого?

Так кто-то придёт, посмотрит, и очень посмеётся над этим. Так что нас надо не поздравлять, а ругать! ;-)

[image: Управление картинкой с БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ]

Comment: если посмотреть с другой стороны:  У нас из 250 вопросов 80% - хорошего качество, а это весьма не мало

Comment: А на enSO ещё похуже дела обстоят с качеством.

Comment: А что такого страшного в этом вопросе? Вроде автору нужна просто какая-то приблуда на веб-сокетах, которая будет динамически менять SVG на основе базы данных. Самая обычная задача.

Comment: @MSDNWhiteKnight, там же написал он: «Управление SVG по его id с БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ». И затем ещё, когда его не поняли, [сделал уточнение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/827667/revisions) (см. версию 6): «Управление SVG по его id с PHP MY ADMIN». Дело в том, что он хочет одно, а на деле ему надо другое. Один участник  решил ему помочь и потратил своё время.

Comment: @Bharata Ну да, ясность изложения хромает (он походу не понимает, разницы между MySQL и PHP My Admin, поэтому так и написал). Но это не криминально. Если участник не понял вопроса и бросился сразу писать ответ вместо уточнения в комментариях - его проблемы.

Comment: @Bharata: 86% статистики из пальца высосано (процент плохих вопросов выше 20%). Если видите плохой вопрос, который нельзя улучшить, то голосуйте за закрытие. Есть кнопки: голосания, "править", "закрыть", "тревога", "добавить комментарий" -- используйте их.  Если видите ошибочный ответ/комментарий, оставьте свой с уточнением.

Comment: @jfs, я пользуюсь тревогами, но они, видимо, из-за нехватки рук частенько висят у меня в ожидании по нескольку дней. А что касается обращений к вопрошающим, то бывают такие из них непробиваемые, которые «гнут свою палку», что не хочется их спрашивать более. Вышеописанный вопрошающий как раз такой.

Comment: Допустим, если сердце остановилось, то без свидетелей шансы выживания 4% процента, если кто-то CPR сделает, то — 8%. То есть даже если 92% процента умрёт после ваших действий, то всё равно стоит CPR делать, так как это шансы в два раза повышает на выживание¶ Если ваши действия не всегда успешны (не 100% эффективны), это ещё не значит, что не нужно их выполнять.

Answer (score 9):

Честно - ещё недавно я бы радовался как... кто-то очень радостный.
Но в связи с последними событиями, как-то не выходит.
Хотя я стараюсь, это ведь событие есть хорошо.

Но то, чем пришлось пожертвовать ради таких больших цифр, меня не радует.

Типа ура!

Comment: М? Можно конкретнее?

Comment: @D-side допускаю, что речь в частности о топовом участнике, который, судя по всему, покинул руСО

Comment: @alexolut [этом](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44786234#44786234)? Мне не вполне понятно, как это связано с "жертвой больших цифр ради".

Comment: @D-side есть мнение, что слишком сильно проявляется перекос в сторону интересов новичков с целью максимизации количества юзеров и вопросов, методы идут в разрез с интересами и пожеланиями ряда активно отвечающих, появляется ощущения того, что местная демократия сломалась.

Comment: @D-side, yolosora верно подметил (-а). Мне не нравится что в погоне за показателями, под каток репрессий идут важные, на мой взгляд, вещи.

Comment: @yolosora на мой взгляд, он ушёл вовсе не из-за излишнего новичкодружелюбия, а [неуважения администрации к участникам сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44784820#44784820). Во всяком случае, то как он это объясняет, наталкивает на этот мотив. А тема плохих вопросов где-то далеко сбоку.

Comment: @D-side, Влад попал под каток и это печально. Но пост не только из-за него, а "неуважение администрации" и "поощрение плохих вопросов" связаны аж очень сильно. В нашем случае.

Comment: @Other вот из ответа мне это ни капельки не очевидно. Я практически перестал участвовать в жизни сообщества (причины Влада мне тоже близки, но это не всё), так что не в курсе последних событий. Можете развернуть мысль?

Comment: @D-side, Была эпичная битва с тем, что администрация прямо сказала что мнение сообщества - не более чем рекомендация, так что мнение, может, есть, но легко завернётся менеджером (вроде на это Влад обиделся), а сейчас мы, опять же, не спросив мнения сообщества, вводим ещё более лояльную политику к новичкам.

Comment: @Other последовательность во времени понятна, но таки где связь?

Comment: @D-side связь - *некоторые* участники расстроились, узнав что они просто участники на сайте вопросов и ответов. То, что администрация, которая платит за все, от разработки до рекламы, имеет на сайте решающий голос, стало для них неприятным открытием и разрушило хрупкую иллюзию демократии и полного контроля сообщества за всем происходящим на сайте :(

Comment: @PashaPash, Моего ответа нет, т. к. он был в чате. Лично я не этим расстроен, а тем, что заявлено что мнение участников важно, но на деле - нет (взять тот же закон о ещё большей лояльности к плохим вопросам). Безусловно, они заказали банкет - они с него профит и имеют. Но тогда не надо говорить что участники что-то решают, а сразу установить правила диктатуры. В этом случае я бы сразу мог понять - нужно ли мне тут быть с таким уставом или нет.

Comment: @Other Диктату́ра (лат. dictatura) — форма осуществления *государственной* власти. У нас не государство. Вы ставите вопрос как "или у нас участники решают все, и администрация **обязана** подчиниться" (очевидно, что не обязана и не будет обязана) или "у нас диктатура, к мнению участников никто и никогда не прислушивается" (что тоже, очевидно, не соответствует реальной картине).

Comment: @Other По непонятной причине ответ "у нас не диктатура и не демократия, у нас ресурс с администрацией, которая старается прислушиваться к мнению активных участников сообщества, и часто, но не всегда ему следует" вас не устраивает. Было бы Мнение участников важно, но оно - **не закон**, мы не государство, и Николас никого не бросит в тюрьму и не расстреляет за нарушение "навязанных" администрацией же правил.

Comment: Есть в риторике правило, гласящее что при отсутствии годных аргументов, надо сделать акцент на чём-то неважном в словах оппонента, вроде уместности применения типа государственного строя в коммерческом проекте. Просто правило, к чему бы его тут применить?

Comment: Повторю в последний, надеюсь, раз - я не призываю делегировать власть, пусть у владельцев она будет, но и про общество не надо забывать.

Comment: @Other ок. почему вы решили, что сейчас владельцы забывают про сообщество?

Comment: @PashaPash, Хотите конкретного примера? ОК, принуждение к бинайсовости² для нагона трафика. Сообщество (некоторые участники) не одобряет эту идею. Как администрация на это смотрит?

Comment: @Other хотелось бы увидеть конкретные примеры "принуждения к бинайсовости". давайте обсуждать в один поток в чате: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44934249#44934249

Comment: Простите, но мне не понятны ваши рассуждения. Вы хоите, чтобы был закрытый клуб на 500 человек, в который принимали бы только сеньеров? В чем же будет смысл от такого сообщества? Stack overflow должен распространять знания, я думаю.

Comment: @PashaPash я не совсем согласен с вашим отказом принимать понятия связанные с государственностью к данному ресурсу. Параллели мне кажутся очевидными, есть "власть" - администрация, есть "граждане" - пользователи, есть "законы" - свод правил и соглашений, нарушая "законы" можно "попасть в тюрьму" или быть "расстреляным" - бан на срок или уже удаление учетной записи. Есть даже выборная "судебная власть" в виде модераторов. Почему бы тогда и формы осуществления власти не попробовать сюда припараллелить?

Comment: @yolosora, Да это бесполезно, проверено на практике.

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev мне же непонятны ваши – почему обязательно должна быть крайность в ту или иную сторону? Сообщество неплохо выполняло свою миссию и потихоньку развивалось между крайностей.