# Планируется ли на ru.SO "промежуточная площадка" для первых вопросов?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, первые-вопросы

Увидел, что на англоязычном SO тестируется [фильтрующая площадка для первых вопросов](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-staging-ground). Планируется ли введение подобного и у нас? Какие вы видите плюсы или минусы, если это будет внедрено?

Comment: Наконец, хоть что-то. Давно предлагал структурировать ruSO

Comment: @avp а где предлагали? Вопрос с меткой [meta-tag:предложение] есть?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, в комментариях, естественно (я же всерьез во все эти ваши игры не лезу)

Answer (score 6):

Я недавно постил [баг-репорт](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387894/339911), так что вряд ли оно переедет на те сайты, где активность достаточно мала (по сравнению с большим SO). По [текущей статистике](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday) разница в кол-ве вопросов в день (3821 против 119) >32 раза.
<sub>Интересно, что с анонса пятилетней давности о [250 вопросах в день](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7399/176217) показатели упали в 2 раза. Причём по всем сайтам, которые видно на скриншоте.</sub>

То есть у нас не столь остро стоит проблема плохих вопросов, сколько наличия вопросов вообще.

При включении данной схемы количество плохих вопросов очевидно уменьшится, но и скорость публикации (от момента отправки вопроса автором до публикации на сайте) упадёт. Если вопрос некому проверить, то на сайт он попадёт по максимальному таймауту, не знаю какой он будет, но явно должен быть достаточным, чтобы как-то проверить вопрос и дать рекомендации. Думаю, что не меньше 5 минут.

Другой момент, что проверяющие качество вопроса, получают преимущество в ответе. Уже во время проверки можно придумать (но не опубликовать) ответ. А схема успешного набивания репы предполагает в том числе быструю публикацию ответа с последующим дописыванием.

Не думаю, что в текущих реалиях Staging Ground будет полезен ruSO.

Comment: Да я согласен, что вопросов гораздо меньше, но и отвечающих, наверное, тоже меньше в десятки раз. Так что то, на то и выходит. А от непроверенных первых вопросов иногда опускаются руки. Зачем допускать к общему обозрению то, что можно отсеять на входе?

Comment: @СергейКох а что такого плохого, если не особо качественный вопрос повисит немного в списке? Если совсем треш, то его удалят и не будет показываться вовсе, если не очень плохой, но непонятный, то закроют (а потом он также может удалиться, если голоса будут отрицательные). В общем, при небольшом потоке вопросов я не вижу в этом какой-то проблемы. Если поток существенный, то предварительная проверка может как сделать контент чище, так и разгрузить модераторов, ревьюверов - проще проверить вопрос сразу, чем потом реагировать на ненужные ответы и комментарии, которые на нём уже наросли.

Comment: "Интересно, что с анонса пятилетней давности о 250 вопросах в день показатели упали в 2 раза." Я думаю, что на многие основные вопросы на которые натыкались программисты уже даны ответы на SO. И сейчас рассматриваются или ошибки возникающие после обновлений или какие-то более частные случаи, так что это не показатель плохой работы SO. Я думаю, что посещаемость сайта растет и нужна некоторая защита от вредоносного мусора, который возникает на пути.

Comment: @СергейКох посещаемость тоже просела (но меньше, чем в 2 раза), см. приведенные ссылки, всё видно.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Что-то в корне идёт не так. Эх.